# Can JRebel reload Kotlin classes when they are used by kotlin-maven-plugin plugin on maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3, kotlin, jrebel, hotdeploy

Can JRebel reload Kotlin classes when they are used by kotlin-maven-plugin plugin on Maven?

The project runs on an application server.

Answer (score 1):

JRebel will reload kotlin classes provided they are compiled either via IDE or manually by invoking maven compile.

Also the classes must either be compiled to the path specified in the rebel.xml or to the classloader's classpath(e.g. when using exploded deployment with `target/classes` or `target/artifact-name/WEB-INF/classes` as the root).

Usually achieving this requires no extra steps and it should be just: Enable JRebel -> Start server & deploy application -> Make changes -> make/compile to reload

If you have not done so yet, please try the free trial at https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/trial/
and report back any issues and suggestions to support@zeroturnaround.com